# want to filter the file names only based on year and month in a text file

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file that contains list of files. I want to filter year and whole month files, where date should be skipped. I tried it with `awk '$6 =="2017-04"' filename.txt` displays all files other than april files well.

```
-rwxrwx---   3 hdfs      hadoop        420 2017-04-04 12:00 
/apps/datafactory/09C8490A1491408019259/hdfs-test-file1.txt
```

Comment: Give more lines of input .. it's not very clear what you're trying to say

Comment: `$6=="2017-04"...` requires an exact match of all chars in the `$6` field, so the trailing `-04` is throwing that off. Try `$6 ~ /2017-04/ ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Hey Shelter/BatMan . Thanks a lot saving my time. it worked. Thanks again. Its filtered only april 2017 files 

awk '$6~/^2017-04/' hdfsuser.txt

Answer (score 1):

assuming the format is YYYY-MM-DD

you can

```
awk 'substr($6,1,7)=="2017-04"`
```

or

```
awk '$6~/^2017-04/'
```

but in either case (including your own) you wouldn't get any false positives.  So you need to support your claim

> ...displays all files other than april files well.

with evidence.